# Using sed to replace a substring with another one

Tags: regex, sed

Take a look at the following paths:

```
/iil/some/path/data/file1
iil/some/path/log/file2
/iil/some/path/BinDir1/file3
iil/some/path/BinDir2/file4
```

I would like to use `sed` in order to convert every substring which starts with `/iil` or `ill` and until it meet one of the following words: `data,log,BinDir*`. So the output will be:

```
[PATH]/data/file1
[PATH]/log/file2
[PATH]/BinDir1//file3
[PATH]/BinDir2/file4
```

What I tried:

```
echo "/iil/path/data/file1" | /usr/bin/sed "s/\(\/|)iil.*\(data\|log\|BinDir*\)/[PATH]\/g"
```

But it does not work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `sed` absolutely required? `sed` does not support non-greedy quantifiers and your `sed` command will match up to the last occurrence of `data`, `log` or `BinDir`. With Perl, it will be simpler, `perl -pe 's,^/?iil/.*?/(data|log|BinDir\d+),/$1,'`. Well, the pattern can  further be enhanced, say, if `data` or `log` can come right after `iil`, use `^/?iil/(?:.*?/)?(data|log|BinDir\d+)`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/X5FMJL).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's a good suggestion, I can use `Perl`. can you enhance the regex so it could catch also `iil/log/file1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `sed` command has some issues:

- The `|` alternation operator  is not escaped in the first group and is matched as a literal pipe symbol since the pattern is parsed as a BRE POSIX regex
- The first group is broken as the trailing `)` is not escaped
- The digit matching pattern is not used, you just quantified `r`, `r*` matches 0+ `r` letters
- There is no placeholder in the RHS and the word captured into Group 2 is removed (though you ruined the command by escaping last `/` delimiter).

You could fix you own command like

```
echo "/iil/path/data/file1" | \
   sed 's/\(\/\|\)iil.*\(data\|log\|BinDir[0-9]\)/[PATH]\2/'
```

See [the demo](https://ideone.com/ddBYvf)

However, you most probably want to match *up to the first* `data`, `log` and `BinDir` that immediately follow the `/`. Thus, I suggest a Perl solution since Perl supports non-greedy quantifiers:

```
perl -pe 's,^/?iil/(?:.*?/)?(data|log|BinDir\d+),/$1,'
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/NKUUQU).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string/line
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `iil/` - a `iil/` substring
- `(?:.*?/)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `(data|log|BinDir\d+)` - Group 1: `data`, or `log` or `BinDir` followed with 1+ digits.

The replacement is `/$1`, a slash and the contents of Group 1.